# fetch_mldata: how to manually set up MNIST dataset when source server is down?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I need to run a code that contains these lines:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
```

There seems to be a problem with executing it.

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

As the code tries to download *something* from *somewhere* and my internet connecton works well, I assume that server that it wants to access is down.

How can I set it up manually?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`fetch_mldata` will by default check the data in `'~/scikit_learn_data/mldata' to see if the dataset is already downloaded or not.

According to [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/datasets/mldata.py#L151)

```
    # if the file does not exist, download it
    if not exists(filename):
        urlname = MLDATA_BASE_URL % quote(dataname)
```

So in your case, it will check the location

```
~/scikit_learn_data/mldata/mnist-original.mat
```

and if not found, it will download from

```
http://mldata.org/repository/data/download/matlab/mnist-original.mat
```

which currently is down as you suspected.

So what you can do is download the dataset from any other location like this:

```
https://github.com/amplab/datascience-sp14/blob/master/lab7/mldata/mnist-original.mat
```

and keep that in the above folder.

After that when you run `fetch_mldata()` it should pick the downloaded dataset without connecting mldata.org.

## Update:

Here `~` refers to the user home folder. You can use the following code to know the default location of that folder according to your system.

```
from sklearn.datasets import get_data_home
print(get_data_home())
```

Comment: what does `~/` mean in file paths? Does `~/scikit_learn_data/mldata/mnist-original.mat` point to `scikit_learn_data` folder inside my project folder (and which is next to python file I execute?)

Comment: @Piotrek No. `~` means the home folder path. Are you using windows or linux?

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: If you follow this method and run into the following error `"ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 105, 116"`, down the dataset from here instead: https://www.kaggle.com/avnishnish/mnist-original