# Error while loading MNIST in Jupyter -> ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, dataset, mnist

I am getting an error while trying to load the MNIST data using following commands:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
mnist
```

I tried removing the mldata folder

```
rm -r ~/scikit_learn_data/mldata/
```

and retried it as per some other answers found on the internet but it is still not working. There is no problem with the internet connection or slow connection as well. Commands used in the above code are correct as it works for others. So looking for a solution to fix this problem for my case. [Note: I am using Ubuntu]

Error:

```
    ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-470941be7ce8> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
----> 2 mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
      3 mnist

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/mldata.py in fetch_mldata(dataname, target_name, data_name, transpose_data, data_home)
    152         urlname = MLDATA_BASE_URL % quote(dataname)
    153         try:
--> 154             mldata_url = urlopen(urlname)
    155         except HTTPError as e:
    156             if e.code == 404:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221     else:
    222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    224 
    225 def install_opener(opener):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    524             req = meth(req)
    525 
--> 526         response = self._open(req, data)
    527 
    528         # post-process response

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _open(self, req, data)
    542         protocol = req.type
    543         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
--> 544                                   '_open', req)
    545         if result:
    546             return result

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    502         for handler in handlers:
    503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 504             result = func(*args)
    505             if result is not None:
    506                 return result

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_open(self, req)
   1344 
   1345     def http_open(self, req):
-> 1346         return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
   1347 
   1348     http_request = AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1319             except OSError as err: # timeout error
   1320                 raise URLError(err)
-> 1321             r = h.getresponse()
   1322         except:
   1323             h.close()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1329         try:
   1330             try:
-> 1331                 response.begin()
   1332             except ConnectionError:
   1333                 self.close()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in begin(self)
    295         # read until we get a non-100 response
    296         while True:
--> 297             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    298             if status != CONTINUE:
    299                 break

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    256 
    257     def _read_status(self):
--> 258         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
    259         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:
    260             raise LineTooLong("status line")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py in readinto(self, b)
    584         while True:
    585             try:
--> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    587             except timeout:
    588                 self._timeout_occurred = True

ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Any other suggestion to fix this problem will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The original source from where this dataset is downloaded is down. See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301570/fetch-mldata-how-to-manually-set-up-mnist-dataset-when-source-server-is-down/51301798#51301798) for work-around.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thank you for answering. I wanted to know the reason behind the error. This explains it. Thanks!