# Connection error while loading mnist dataset from keras Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I am trying to load the mnist dataset using Python's keras library:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

(xt,yt),(xv,yv)=mnist.load_data()
```

The dataset starts downloading normally, but after a while I get the following error:

> ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I have tried downloading the same dataset from another source:

```
from tensorflow.keras import datasets
(xt,yt),(xv,yv)=datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

But I keep getting the same error.

I have also tried the following:

```
mnist=input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/",one_hot=False)
x_train=mnist.train.images

y_train=mnist.train.labels

x_test=mnist.test.images

y_test=mnist.test.labels
```

The data loading was successful but x_train and x_test were loaded as 2D arrays(already reshaped). I actually want the original 3D version (before reshaping) of the Data which I can't seem to load successfully.

Comment: Possible workaround: Do you *need* the 3-D data to be downloaded, or could you reshape it back?

Comment: @jtlz2 I tried it and I think it should work just fine. Thank you very much for pointing this out!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fetch\_mldata: how to manually set up MNIST dataset when source server is down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301570/fetch-mldata-how-to-manually-set-up-mnist-dataset-when-source-server-is-down)